# PHP page view counter

Tags: php

I downloaded a php view counter and I set it the database but when it comes to show the hits I am getting error. The documentation says

- USAGE:

  - In your script, use reqire_once() to import this script, then call the
  - functions like PHPCount::AddHit(...); See each function for help.
    *

Here is my demo.php where I want to show the view. But it is throwing

`Notice: Undefined variable: pageID in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\demo.php on line 4
1`

```
 <?php
include_once("hit.php");
echo //this is what I added.
PHPCount::AddHit($pageID);
?>
```

The below is hit.php and **what I wanna know is how can I show the views on the above demo.php?**

```
    <?php
/*
 * USAGE:
 *        In your script, use reqire_once() to import this script, then call the
 *        functions like PHPCount::AddHit(...); See each function for help.
 *
 * NOTE: You must set the database credentials in the InitDB method.
 */

class PHPCount
{
    /*
    * Defines how many seconds a hit should be rememberd for. This prevents the
    * database from perpetually increasing in size. Thirty days (the default)
    * works well. If someone visits a page and comes back in a month, it will be
    * counted as another unique hit.
     */
     const HIT_OLD_AFTER_SECONDS = 2592000; // default: 30 days.

    // Don't count hits from search robots and crawlers.
    const IGNORE_SEARCH_BOTS = true;

     // Don't count the hit if the browser sends the DNT: 1 header.
const HONOR_DO_NOT_TRACK = false;

private static $IP_IGNORE_LIST = array(
    '127.0.0.1',
);

private static $DB = false;

private static function InitDB()
{
    if(self::$DB)
        return;

    try
    {
        // TODO: Set the database login credentials.
        self::$DB = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
            'root', // Username
            '', // Password
            array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true)
        );
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die('Failed to connect to phpcount database');
    }
}

/*
 * Adds a hit to a page specified by a unique $pageID string.
 */
public static function AddHit($pageID)
{
    if(self::IGNORE_SEARCH_BOTS && self::IsSearchBot())
        return false;
    if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], self::$IP_IGNORE_LIST))
        return false;
    if(
        self::HONOR_DO_NOT_TRACK &&
        isset($_SERVER['HTTP_DNT']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_DNT'] == "1"
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    self::InitDB();

    self::Cleanup();
    self::CreateCountsIfNotPresent($pageID);
    if(self::UniqueHit($pageID))
    {
        self::CountHit($pageID, true);
        self::LogHit($pageID);
    }
    self::CountHit($pageID, false);

    return true;
}

/*
 * Returns (int) the amount of hits a page has
 * $pageID - the page identifier
 * $unique - true if you want unique hit count
 */
public static function GetHits($pageID, $unique = false)
{
    self::InitDB();

    self::CreateCountsIfNotPresent($pageID);

    $q = self::$DB->prepare(
        'SELECT hitcount FROM hits
         WHERE pageid = :pageid AND isunique = :isunique'
    );
    $q->bindParam(':pageid', $pageID);
    $q->bindParam(':isunique', $unique);
    $q->execute();

    if(($res = $q->fetch()) !== FALSE)
    {
        return (int)$res['hitcount'];
    }
    else
    {
        die("Missing hit count from database!");
        return false;
    }
}

/*
 * Returns the total amount of hits to the entire website
 * When $unique is FALSE, it returns the sum of all non-unique hit counts
 * for every page. When $unique is TRUE, it returns the sum of all unique
 * hit counts for every page, so the value that's returned IS NOT the 
 * amount of site-wide unique hits, it is the sum of each page's unique
 * hit count.
 */
public static function GetTotalHits($unique = false)
{
    self::InitDB();

    $q = self::$DB->prepare(
        'SELECT hitcount FROM hits WHERE isunique = :isunique'
    );
    $q->bindParam(':isunique', $unique);
    $q->execute();
    $rows = $q->fetchAll();

    $total = 0;
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        $total += (int)$row['hitcount'];
    }
    return $total;
}

/*====================== PRIVATE METHODS =============================*/

private static function IsSearchBot()
{
    // Of course, this is not perfect, but it at least catches the major
    // search engines that index most often.
    $keywords = array(
        'bot',
        'spider',
        'spyder',
        'crawlwer',
        'walker',
        'search',
        'yahoo',
        'holmes',
        'htdig',
        'archive',
        'tineye',
        'yacy',
        'yeti',
    );

    $agent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

    foreach($keywords as $keyword) 
    {
        if(strpos($agent, $keyword) !== false)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private static function UniqueHit($pageID)
{
    $ids_hash = self::IDHash($pageID);

    $q = self::$DB->prepare(
        'SELECT time FROM nodupes WHERE ids_hash = :ids_hash'
    );
    $q->bindParam(':ids_hash', $ids_hash);
    $q->execute();

    if(($res = $q->fetch()) !== false)
    {
        if($res['time'] > time() - self::HIT_OLD_AFTER_SECONDS)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

private static function LogHit($pageID)
{
    $ids_hash = self::IDHash($pageID);

    $q = self::$DB->prepare(
        'SELECT time FROM nodupes WHERE ids_hash = :ids_hash'
    );
    $q->bindParam(':ids_hash', $ids_hash);
    $q->execute();

    $curTime = time();

    if(($res = $q->fetch()) !== false)
    {
        $s = self::$DB->prepare(
            'UPDATE nodupes SET time = :time WHERE ids_hash = :ids_hash'
        );
        $s->bindParam(':time', $curTime);
        $s->bindParam(':ids_hash', $ids_hash);
        $s->execute();
    }
    else
    {
        $s = self::$DB->prepare(
            'INSERT INTO nodupes (ids_hash, time)
             VALUES( :ids_hash, :time )'
        );
        $s->bindParam(':time', $curTime);
        $s->bindParam(':ids_hash', $ids_hash);
        $s->execute();
    }
}

private static function CountHit($pageID, $unique)
{
    $q = self::$DB->prepare(
        'UPDATE hits SET hitcount = hitcount + 1 ' .
        'WHERE pageid = :pageid AND isunique = :isunique'
    );
    $q->bindParam(':pageid', $pageID);
    $unique = $unique ? '1' : '0';
    $q->bindParam(':isunique', $unique);
    $q->execute();
}

private static function IDHash($pageID)
{
    $visitorID = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    return hash("SHA256", $pageID . $visitorID);
}

private static function CreateCountsIfNotPresent($pageID)
{
    // Non-unique
    $q = self::$DB->prepare(
        'SELECT pageid FROM hits WHERE pageid = :pageid AND isunique = 0'
    );
    $q->bindParam(':pageid', $pageID);
    $q->execute();

    if($q->fetch() === false)
    {
        $s = self::$DB->prepare(
            'INSERT INTO hits (pageid, isunique, hitcount) 
             VALUES (:pageid, 0, 0)'
        );
        $s->bindParam(':pageid', $pageID);
        $s->execute();
    }

    // Unique
    $q = self::$DB->prepare(
        'SELECT pageid FROM hits WHERE pageid = :pageid AND isunique = 1'
    );
    $q->bindParam(':pageid', $pageID);
    $q->execute();

    if($q->fetch() === false)
    {
        $s = self::$DB->prepare(
            'INSERT INTO hits (pageid, isunique, hitcount) 
             VALUES (:pageid, 1, 0)'
        );
        $s->bindParam(':pageid', $pageID);
        $s->execute();
    }
}

private static function Cleanup()
{
    $last_interval = time() - self::HIT_OLD_AFTER_SECONDS;

    $q = self::$DB->prepare(
        'DELETE FROM nodupes WHERE time < :time'
    );
    $q->bindParam(':time', $last_interval);
    $q->execute();
}
}
```

Comment: Because you're not passing an argument to the AddHit method...Did you looked at the code? `function AddHit($pageID)` .

Comment: outsource to google analytics.

Comment: you need to create a `key` called PageID for each page your counting the hits, for example the page id for your `index.php` can be `$pageID = 'index'`

Comment: @DamienPirsy the $pageID was what I added. so what would be the correct procedure to show the views?

Comment: According to hit.php, the function AddHit() takes one parameter with the name $pageID. You try to call this function without a Parameter, that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to specify the PageID

```
PHPCount::AddHit("index");
```

Comment: yeah that is inserting the views to database but I am not able to see the views still. It only shows 1.

Comment: Are you using PHPCount::GetHits("index") to retrieve the hit count?